# $(3\ 5)(2 \ 4)(5 \ 6)$ has the same cycle type as $(2 \ 4)(3 \ 5\ 6)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I see that $\sigma_2 = (3\  5)(2 \ 4)(5 \ 6)$ has the same cycle type as $(2 \ 4)(3 \ 5\ 6)$?

> Determine whether or not $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are conjugate. If they are, find a permutation $\tau$ such that $\tau\sigma_1\tau^{-1} = \sigma_2$.
>   $$\sigma_1 = (1\ 3)(2\ 4\ 6), \sigma_2 = (3\ 5)(2\ 4)(5\ 6)$$

Answer (score 3):

So you know permutations are conjugate iff they have the same cycle type.

A permutation's cycle type can be read off of its [*disjoint* cycle representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index#Disjoint_cycle_representation_of_permutations).

So find the disjoint cycle representation of $(3~5)(2~4)(5~6)$. Know how?

Comment: Oh... Got it~ thank you anon

Answer (score 2):

> For permutations $x,y\in S_n$ where $x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots,\xi_n)$ we have $$y^{-1}xy=(\xi_1^y,\xi_2^y,\cdots,\xi_n^y)$$

Thinking about $\tau=(1,5,6,4,3,2)$ for example.